# How to convert accentuated char into number (int) cpp?

Tags: c++, encoding, typeconverter

So i'm trying to convert é à â into int

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string  a =  "é";
    unsigned long b = (unsigned long) a[0];
    cout << (string) b << endl;
    /* error: no matching conversion for C-style cast from 'unsigned 
       long' to 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, 
       allocator<char> >') 
    */
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I already did it with (char) etc...
So here i'am i'm think it is a problem of encoding hope you can help.

Comment: s/`std::cout << (char) - 61 << endl;`/`std::cout << (unsigned char) - 61 << endl;`

Comment: You should have a look at how encoding work, e.g. in Wikipedia.

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org/ ; find a good Unicode/UTF-8 library e.g.https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/ ; details could be computer & operating system specific

Answer (score 2):

You have *two* encoding issues to deal with:

- How your compiler converts your source code to object data
- How you convert the object data to a number

In my perfect world, I would have my source in UTF-8 and my compiler producing a UTF-8 string (and not one of the Windows encodings). That’s step 1.

Step two: convert the UTF-8-encoded string to a Unicode code point.

If you wish it to be in some other specific encoding, you must make sure 1) your compiler is encoding that string in some (known to you) way and 2) you can decode it to its numeric representation.

If you use UTF-8, you will have to decode two bytes to get your number. If you use UTF-16 or UTF-32, you will get it in a single code point. If you use something like CP-1252 you will also get it in a single byte, but it won’t have the same numeric value as it does in Unicode.

Figure out these things and the conversion is easy.